# Create a model that inherits two model in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

Is there a way to create a `model` that inherits two `model`?

```
#electric class
class Electric(models.Model):
    _name = 'electric'

    battery = fields.Integer()

#combustion class
class Combustion(models.Model):
    _name = 'combustion'

    fuel_tank = fields.Integer()

#inherit from electric and combustion
class Hybrid(models.Model):
    _name = 'hybrid'
    _inherit = 'combustion'
    _inherit = 'electric'
```

This code does not work. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Odoo multi model inheritance is performed in the following way..

```
class Hybrid(models.Model):
    _name = 'hybrid'
    _inherit = ['combustion','electric']
```

In the case of multi model inheritance, you should define a `_name` property.
The reason being...

**If the _name as the same value as the inherited class it will do a basic inheritance.
If you forget to add the _inherit you will redefine the model If your class _inherit one model and you set a _name different it will create a new model in a new database table.
If your class inherit many model you have to set _name if your override an existing model this way you may have some trouble, it should be avoided. It is better to use this to create new classes that inherit from abstract model.**